# Bypass ISP Block

Tags: proxy, isp

is there anyway I can bypass ISP block to access website? I'm aware of proxy online but the flash video cannot play. I tried using open source dns but it seems to still use ISP's proxy.

Comment: User974459, just to warn you, questions about "circumvention of security or policy" are explicitly off-topic as per the FAQ, which is linked at the top of your screen, so this question will very likely get closed soon.  Please don't take it personally, but you might want to read the FAQ before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any decent VPN provider can give you a VPN access with an IP outside your provider block.